# Export Google Translate results as CSV?

Tags: google-chrome, export-to-csv, google-translate

I typically open a Google Translate page and start filling it up with words. GT has a left text box for the foreign word and a right text box for the translation

```
Von wegen             Are you kidding me?
haften                adhere
Grübeln               brood
mausern               moult
Besonnenheit          calm
Gelassenheit          serenity
einvernehmlich        mutual agreement
Landtag               Parliament
```

So the left column and the right column as separate text boxes, level word-for-word, foreign word and translation. I tried a bit of Emacs org-mode Google capture -- to no avail. Then it dawned on me that if I can get GT to simply export these two (matched up) text boxes as CSV or a spreadsheet, that would be what I wanted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can export the original-translated text pair to Google Sheets (and from there to CSV) by doing the following:

1. Once translated, click on the star below the translation to save it.
2. Click the circled star at the top of the page to show your saved translations.
3. Click on the Export to Google Sheets icon on the top right.

Note that you'll need to be signed in with your Google account to be able to save your translations.

Also, for proper export you should save your words/sentences one at a time so you have one row per translation.

Comment: It's probably better discipline to keep the translation page clean, i.e., not load it up like I do; rather, save off each and every single translation in the spreadsheet. It will take some getting used to. Thanks. BTW, where is a good source for the latest in these sorts of "Google Hacks"? The actual books (from O'Reilly) by that name are way out of date.

Comment: These books are quite old indeed. I'm not aware of any newer edition or books for that purpose though.